# Need to reverse Audio Frequency Step formula

Tags: c++, math

As you see at the below picture, I have a **Logarithmic** Frequency board, Start at 20Hz to 20kHz drawn on a Fixed size (500px) UI (By Qt)

I used this formula for get and draw numbers and lines "Previous_Value*= pow(2,1.0/50) "

Now I try write a formula with Frequency as Input (20 to 20000) and calculate **EXACT** value of X , which is a float number between 0 and 500, Is there any solution to reverse that formula [or] find X value in another way?

[Frequency steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKQRP.png)

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

f = 20.0 * pow(2.0, x/50.0)

x = (50.0/log(2.0)) * log(f/20.0)

Comment: Tnx a lot Mr. Surviver , unfortunately i can't vote to your correct answer

Comment: @HMD You can mark it as correct when the countdown has ended, and upvote it when you've enough reputation.